# How can I get the point coordinates from a vector layer in openlayers3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have created using OpenLayer3 a map with a vector layer.
What I want to do now is to iterate through the vector layer, get the coordinates and store them in an array.

I tried something like this:

```
var store = vectorLayer.getGeometry().getExtent();
```

But I get an undefined function warning.

I also tried doing this:

```
var source = layer.getSource();
var features = source.getFeatures();
```

But I also get the undefined function warning:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getExtent' of undefined
```

Thats part of my code:

```
var url="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?&service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=dSpatialAnalysis:categoriesdata";
var shops_layer=new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'Shops',
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: '/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url='+ encodeURIComponent(url),
        format: new ol.format.WFS({
        })
    }),
    style: iconStyle

});


map = new ol.Map({
    target:'map',
    renderer:'canvas',
    view: view,
    layers: [newLayer, shops_layer],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't change the final result but can be done with [`forEachFeature`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#forEachFeature):

```
var source = shops_layer.getSource();
source.forEachFeature(function(feature){
  var coord = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Much more elegant than mine. Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it after all:

```
    // First access the source of the vectore layer
    var source = shops_layer.getSource();
    // Get the features of the layer 
    var features = source.getFeatures();
    var feature;
   // iterate through the array
    for (var i = 0, ii = features.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        feature = features[i];
        // get the geometry for each feature point
        geometry = feature.getGeometry();
        // get the first coordinate
        geometry_coords = geometry.getFirstCoordinate()
        // assign them to two variables
        geometry_coord_x = console.log(geometry_coords[0]);
        geometry_coord_y = console.log(geometry_coords[1]);

    }
```